# Ошибка в package

Tags: java, intellij-idea

> Error:java: Fatal Error: Unable to find package java.lang in classpath
>   or bootclasspath

Что это за ошибка? из-за чего она возникает и как можно решить?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3049433/intellij-gives-fatal-error-unable-to-find-package-java-lang-in-classpath-or-boo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо Всем, но на самом деле это я сглупил.
оказалось, что я не верно открыл в идеи директорию с моим файлом. у меня было вложение типо (`studentsApp\hello\untitled\src\main.java`)
Я открыл только директорию src, а как оказалось, нужно было открывать с `studetnsApp`

Answer (score 4):

Либо установлен криво JDK, либо Идея криво поставлена. Попробуйте переустановить JDK и правильно настроить переменную PATH. 
Если не поможет, то возможно это баг Идеи, на английском StackOverflow такое вот решение:[решение на StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3049433/intellij-gives-fatal-error-unable-to-find-package-java-lang-in-classpath-or-boo)

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте свойство библиотеку вашего проекта и если может там вы установили другую JDK и не изменение указали в свойстве системе(Смотрите что там все правильно переменные среды JAVA_HOME и Path потом перезагружать) или проекта(JDK,Language level, Java compiler )